# daterangepicker getting the value that passed it from view but it give date and year correct but the it selected the correct month

Tags: javascript, jquery, daterangepicker

when selecting the edit button daterangepicker gets the value that passed it from view (it gets the correct value I debug it) but when I passed it to the input daterangepicker field it give the date and year correct but it selected the correct month instead of the month mention in value.
If any of you have a solution please tell me.

```
$('#datefilter2').val(datefilter2);
    $('.datefilter').daterangepicker({
        "singleDatePicker": true,
        "showDropdowns": true,
        "timePicker": true,
        startDate: moment().startOf('hour'),
        endDate: moment().startOf('hour').add(32, 'hour'),
        'minDate': today,
        autoUpdateInput: false,
        locale: {
            cancelLabel: 'Clear',
            format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'
        }
    });
```

after debugging the datefilter2 give the correct date but not select the correct month in the field.

Comment: could you create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example please

Comment: @patrick Thank you. I have resolved the solution. When I extract the date, month, year and date I used the wrong month variable that's why I get the wrong month there.

Comment: glad you sorted it